# How to set up logical postgresql replication correctly (two ways)?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I can not solve this problem:

If there are 2 postgresql servers, logical replication (publishing, subscribers) of some tables is used, if it works in one direction - everything is fine, but horror begins in both directions.

Those. On server1 and on server2 there are identical databases with the same tasks table.
According to the replica, from server1 to server2 only INSERT and UPDATE are transmitted, then on server2, the logic processes the tasks and writes updates the status to tasks, which accordingly flies back to server1 (only UPDATE is taken back to the server).

The problem is that we get a looped replica (it’s enough on the first server to set status 1, then set status 2 on server2 and we see that in our tables the status of the task will change infinitely from 1 to 2 and vice versa endlessly, which makes it difficult with data and litters the logs.
Unfortunately, there is no way to change the application logic. From ideas, only to include a return response as necessary (that is, not in real-time, but according to a certain schedule so that the status is fixed)

Comment: Why replicate at all? Can't you use one of the servers as the "source-of-truth" and then use foreign tables to access the data from the other server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I could be wrong, but if you set up foreign table on another server, then all queries to this table will be actually executed on the original server, while data will be even not stored on our so-called "replica". Thus, we do not achieve neither performance boost, nor data safety.

Comment: With a foreign table you are actually distributing the load of one server to two servers ;) You should have included those requirements. Another option is to use a master/slave setup and do load balancing of the read queries (e.g. through pgPool or pgBouncer). If your application does more reads than writes this is probably the easiest way to scale (and you can have multiple slaves to distribute the load)

Comment: The key points of replication are: 1) data backup and failover; 2) split read access between master and replica, so-called "hot standby" in Postgres. With Multi-master you can share write queries as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, agree. But still cannot get it, why you will distribute load with foreign table. As I understand, with foreign table you only distribute connections between two servers (like connection pooling), while all actual work (index scans, disk reads, sorts, etc) will be performed on the original server. Will check code and docs again to be sure :)

Comment: If you e.g. join a local table and a foreign table you distribute the load between the two servers. Some people use e.g. foreign tables together with partitioning and put different partitions on different servers. That way queries that involve multiple partitions can be executed on different servers distributing the I/O and CPU load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JosMac has already mentioned you need [Multi-master replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication), which is currently not supported in the PostgreSQL core (v11-12 at the date). There are [various Multi-master solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication#PostgreSQL) for PostgreSQL, but if you want to stick to the open-source you can try [Postgres-XL](https://www.postgres-xl.org/).

Comment: Hoped you could do this on the original Postgres, thanks. The question is closed